# PHP strtotime needs adjustment

Tags: php, wordpress, strtotime

I'm working on a php function to calculate total time between two user-input time fields from a wordpress forms plugin, but the function is not working when the times cross 2400 hours.

Here's the exact situation: I'm trying to calculate how long a user slept but I get a negative number when the start time is in the evening (23:00 for example) and the end time (wake up) is the next morning (07:00 for example) - this is because the times are taken from a a form that shows both times on the same day, so the start time appears greater than the end time when converted using strtotime.

Here is the original code:

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'calculate_time', 11, 3);
function calculate_time($errors, $field, $value){
if($field->id == 98){ //98 is the field id from the wordpress plugin that will store the total time I'm using
  $start = (strtotime($_POST['item_meta'][88])); //88 is the field id for 'go to sleep time' from the wordpress forms program - the user selects times from 00:00 to 23:00
  $end = (strtotime($_POST['item_meta'][78])); //78 is the field id for 'wake up time' from the wordpress forms program - the user selects times from 00:00 to 23:00
  $totaltime = ($end - $start);
  $hours = intval($totaltime / 3600);   
  $seconds_remain = ($totaltime - ($hours * 3600)); 
  $minutes = intval($seconds_remain / 60);
  $totaltime = $hours . ':' . $minutes; 
  $value = $_POST['item_meta'][98] = $totaltime; //change 25 to the ID of the hidden or admin only field which will hold the calculation
}
return $errors;
}
```

Here is how I tried to adjust by adding twelve hours to the end time if it was less than the start time:

```
add_filter('frm_validate_field_entry', 'calculate_time', 11, 3);
function calculate_time($errors, $field, $value){
if($field->id == 98){ 
  $start = (strtotime($_POST['item_meta'][88]));
  $end = (strtotime($_POST['item_meta'][78])); 

  if ($end < $start) {
    $end = ($end + 43200)
    $totaltime = ($end - $start);
    $hours = intval($totaltime / 3600);   
    $seconds_remain = ($totaltime - ($hours * 3600)); 
    $minutes = intval($seconds_remain / 60);
    $totaltime = $hours . ':' . $minutes;   
    $value = $_POST['item_meta'][98] = $totaltime; 

} else 

{

  $totaltime = ($end - $start);
  $hours = intval($totaltime / 3600);   
  $seconds_remain = ($totaltime - ($hours * 3600)); 
  $minutes = intval($seconds_remain / 60);
  $totaltime = $hours . ':' . $minutes; 
  $value = $_POST['item_meta'][98] = $totaltime; 
}
}
return $errors;
```

Comment: use the full date\time

Comment: https://secure.php.net/DateTime

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) states

> ```
> int strtotime ( string $time [, int $now = time() ] )
> ```
>
> The function expects to be given a string containing an English date format and will try to parse that format into a Unix timestamp (the number of seconds since January 1 1970 00:00:00 UTC), *relative to the timestamp given in now, or the current time if now is not supplied.*

In your case, both times are interpreted relative to today, i.e. this morning 7am and tonight 11pm.

To fix this, it is sufficient to either adjust by a whole day, e.g. `24*60*60` seconds, or give tomorrow's date as the base for the end. So instead of two large branches, have a small adjustment at the beginning and then calculate the difference uniformly

```php
$start = strtotime($_POST['item_meta'][88]);
$end = strtotime($_POST['item_meta'][78]);
if ($end < $start)
    $end += 86400; // shift the end 24 hours into tomorrow

$totaltime = $end - $start;
```

---

Unrelated, but you don't need to calculate hours and minutes manually, use [`DateTime::format`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) instead

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('U', $totaltime);
$s = $date->format('H:I');
```